# Most efficient way to retrieve a set of LDAP records?

Tags: ldap

I have a set of UIDs - let's say around 200. What is the most efficient way to retrieve all their LDAP records?

The first thing that comes to mind is a query that's a big chain of ORs:

```
(|(uid=jdoe)(uid=mdawson)(uid=fwright)...)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927499/ldap-query-syntax-to-compare-to-a-list suggests the OR is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what object properties you're retrieving and the locality of the LDAP server.  I've found it faster at times (depending on circumstances) to just grab everything, store it locally in a cache, and then search the local cache for what I want.

200 records is really not very many; I'm wondering are you optimizing something that doesn't need to be optimized?

Comment: I don't know if it would be a good idea to locally cache about 6000 users.  For whatever reason, large "or" queries are taking about 45% as long as querying individually, so the improvement is valuable, i.e. 4 seconds instead of 10 seconds for 250 users. I'd still like it to be faster...